# Why can't a statement be added on the same line in a record expression?

Tags: f#

Hm, well that was a hard question to name appropriately. Anyway, I'm wondering why, given this type declaration

```
type T = {
    C : int
}
```

This does not compile:

```
let foo () =
    {
        C = printfn ""; 3
    }
```

but this does:

```
let foo () =
    {
        C = 
            printfn ""; 3
    }
```

Compiler bug or by design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Works as designed" probably more than a "bug", but it's just an overall weird thing to do.

Semicolon is an expression sequencing operator (as in your intended usage), but also a record field separator. In the first case, the parser assumes the latter, and gets confused by it. In the second case, by indenting it you make it clear that the semicolon means expression sequencing.

You could get away with this without splitting the field over two lines:

```
let foo () =
    {
        C = (printfn ""; 3)
    }
```

Comment: More evidence that it's the record field separator:  If you use a long-form expression, you can put it on one line:  `C = let x = 3 in printfn "Test"; x`

Comment: It's even more clear when you try doing the same thing with lists - as semicolon is also a list element separator.